# Simple algorithm but running out of memory

Tags: java, algorithm, memory

> **Problem**
>
> A sequence of positive rational numbers is defined as follows:
>
> An infinite full binary tree labeled by positive rational numbers is
>   defined by:
>
> - The label of the root is 1/1
> - The left child of label p/q is p/(p+q)
> - The right child of label p/q is (p+q)/q
>
> The top of the tree is shown in the following figure:
>
> [image]
>
> The sequence is defined by doing a level order (breadth first)
>   traversal of the tree (indicated by the light dashed line). So that:
>
> F(1)=1/1,F(2)=1/2,F(3)=2/1,F(4)=1/3,F(5)=3/2,F(6)=2/3,…
>
> Write a program which finds the value of n for which F(n) is p/q for
>   inputs p and q.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of input contains a single integer P, (1≤P≤1000), which
>   is the number of data sets that follow. Each data set should be
>   processed identically and independently. Each data set consists of a
>   single line of input. It contains the data set number, K, a single
>   space, the numerator, p, a forward slash (/) and the denominator, q,
>   of the desired fraction.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each data set there is a single line of output. It contains the
>   data set number, K, followed by a single space which is then followed
>   by the value of n for which F(n) is p/q. Inputs will be chosen so n
>   will fit in a 32-bit integer.

[Source to question](https://open.kattis.com/problems/rationalsequence2)

**My approach**

I create the heap and planned to iterate over it until I find the element(s) in question, but I ran out of memory so I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to do it without creating the heap at all?

**Code**

```
public ARationalSequenceTwo() {

    Kattio io = new Kattio(System.in, System.out);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10000);
    int iter = io.getInt();

    // create heap
    int parent;
    Node[] heap = new Node[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    int counter = 1;
    heap[0] = new Node(1, 1);
    while (counter < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        parent = (counter - 1) / 2;
        // left node
        heap[counter++] = new Node(heap[parent].numerator, heap[parent].numerator + heap[parent].denominator);
        // right node
        heap[counter++] = new Node(heap[parent].numerator + heap[parent].denominator, heap[parent].denominator);
    }

    // find Node
    int dataSet;
    String word;
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        dataSet = io.getInt();
        word = io.getWord();
        numerator = Integer.parseInt(word.split("/")[0]);
        denominator = Integer.parseInt(word.split("/")[1]);
        for (int j = 0; j < Integer.MAX_VALUE; j++) {

            Node node = heap[j];
            if (node.numerator == numerator && node.denominator == denominator) {
                sb.append(dataSet).append(" ").append(j).append("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
    io.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can't fit an infinite tree into the finite memory of your computer ...

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE is  2,147,483,647. You are creating that many nodes. Of course it will run out of memory

Comment: So I've spent some time trying to figure out how I can do that. I'm pretty sure layers and a counter could be useful.

Comment: This problem is asking you to find a formula  `F(n)` and an algorithm for computing the function for arbitrary `n`, not actually traverse the tree...

Comment: Read about the Stern Brocot tree. This might help, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Sequence_length_and_index_of_a_fraction

Comment: I wrote an implementation of `F(n)` and then realized it had nothing to do with the question. Anyway, here it is: http://pastebin.com/raw/WUs6ZS2S

Answer (score 2):

let's consider node n = a/b. If n is a left child of its parent, then n = p/(p+q), where the parent is p/q. I.e.

```
p = a, 
b = p + q 

p = a, 
q = b - a
```

If n is a right child of its parent, then n = (p+q)/q:

```
a = p + q
b = q

p = a - b =
q = b
```

so, given for example 3/5, is it a left child or a right child? If it was a left child, then it's parent would be 3/(5-3) = 3/2. For the right child, we would have (3-5)/5 = -2/5. As this would not be positive, clearly n is a left child.

So, generalizing:

given a rational n, we can find the path to the root as follows:

ArrayList lefts = new ArrayList<>();

```
while (nNum != nDen) {
  if (nNum < nDen) {
    //it's a left child
    nDen = nDen - nNum;
    lefts.add(true);
  } else {
    nNum = nNum - nDen;
    lefts.add(false);
  }
}
```

Now that we have the path in the array, how do we translate it in the final result? Let's observe that

- if the value given was 1/1, then the array is empty, and we should return 1
- Every time we go from level n to level n+1, we add 2^n to the result. For example, going from level 0 to level 1 we add 1 (the root). going from level 1 to level 2 we add all two nodes of level 1, which are 2, etc.

We're left with the last piece, which is adding the nodes to the left of the last node we have, the one corresponding to the input rational, plus one. How many node are on the left? if you try to label each arc going left with 0 and each arc going right with 1, you'll notice that the path spells in binary the number of nodes in the last level. For example, 3/5 is the left child of 3/2. the array will be populated with false, true, false. in binary, 010. The final result is 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 010 + 1 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 10

Finally, note that sum(2^i) is 2^(i+1) - 1. so, we can finally write the code for the second part:

```
int s = (1 << lefts.size()) - 1) // 2^(i+1) - 1
int k = 0
for (int i = lefts.size() - 1; i >= 0; i---) {
  if (lefts.get(i)) { 
    k += 1 << i;
  }  
}
return s + k + 1;
```

A full program taking in input num and den:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Z {
  public static int func(int num, int den) {
    ArrayList<Boolean> lefts = new ArrayList<>();
    while (num != den) {
      if (num < den) {
        //it's a left child
        den = den - num;
        lefts.add(true);
      } else {
        num = num - den;
        lefts.add(false);
      }
    }
    int s = (1 << lefts.size()) - 1; // 2^(i+1) - 1
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = lefts.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (!lefts.get(i)) {
        k += 1 << i;
      }
    }
    return s + k + 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(func(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(args[1])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a number p/q you can see whether it's a left or right child of its parent by considering whether p > q or p < q. And one can repeat that process all the way up the tree back to the root.

That gives a relatively simple recursive solution. In pseudocode:

```
T(p, q) =
   1                  if p == q == 1
   2 * T(p, q-p)      if p < q
   2 * T(p-q, q) + 1  if p > q
```

This in theory could cause a stack overflow, because it runs in O(p+q) time and space. For example, T(1000000, 1) will require 1 million recursive calls. But it's given in the question that T(p, q) < 2**31, so the depth of the tree can be at most 32, and this solution works just fine.